# Is "Calculator bug" a code issue?

Tags: windows, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy, calculator

I have seen this bug in many blog posts:
http://atifsiddiqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/windows-calculator-bug.html

Is this bug a code bug or a mathematical imprecision ?

I am wondering if its really a bug, How it got undetected for years ?

What should I take care to make sure that it doesn't happen in my custom caculator program.

Comment: It is **not** a bug (computers work this way!). There are *a lot* of questions on this topic at SO. Search for "JavaScript math broken", for instance.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/208887/windows-calculator-showing-strange-output/208890#208890

Comment: Please read http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You can't tell apart a bug from a feature if you don't read the program requirements ...

Comment: Even infinite precision won't make it possible to represent 1/3 in decimal or 1/10 in binary exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug.  The fact that it has a technical explanation (which is hardly acceptable to the layperson) does not absolve it from being a bug.  If it's not a bug then you are either arguing that - as we all do on occasion - "it's a feature", or that it is a limitation of the system.

To resolve it I'd suggest you round every result to an acceptable precision level to remove the very small error.  As the other answers suggest, the problem is that in your calculator the square root of '4' is not '2', but rather a number very close to 2.  To resolve this round the result to 10, 20, 30 decimal places or whatever you can afford.

I'd argue that any calculator engine should have an underlying level of precision that exceeds the accessible level of precision by a large enough margin so that the user is not able to access the limits of float point arithmetic.  You'll lose one form of 'accuracy' if you take this path, but you simply state that your calculator is accurate to n decimal places.  That's more than acceptable especially if it resolves this issue.

However it's not really a big deal, is it?

---

As an aside, I once worked on a financial application where a vendor provided some software which was supposed to compute some compounding interest rates.  Their calculations were always off.  They argued that it was 'due to floating point arithmetic' and tried to educate me on the issue; but their algorithm was way off.  When compounding interest rates on dollar amounts, we always *round* the total after each iteration (day, week, month, year or whatever).  Depending on the situation it may round to the nearest dollar, nearest cent, or nearest 100th of a cent - but it is a quantifiable amount, and we never compound millionths of a cent from year to year.  This is the approach that you should take if you want to avoid what is essentially a computation rounding error.

Comment: Ah, but then you should've described the requirement to the vendor! After all, working for the financial domain would make one assume that every little penny counts!

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Kirk Broadhurst that this is technically a bug, as the result of sqrt(4)-2 is strictly 0, while Calc gives a different (albeit extremely close) result. The fact that usually we can live with this imprecision is irrelevant here. Strictly speaking, the programmers should have seeked different approaches for solving this kind of problems.

IMHO, what many people here fail to see is that 4 and 2 are precisely representable in IEEE floating point format. Being a natural power of 2 makes it representable to infinite precision, so the arguments blaming the FP format are irrelevant as well. The problem comes from the sqrt() function algorithm and not from the FP storage format.

Comment: the sqrt algorithm might be browken indeed, but these "noise" numbers apeears in most of floating-point operations. As long as the result is so small i think it would be better to simlpy consider it as being 0.

Comment: @Quamis The program should consider it to be 0; the user shouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 3):

**As others have said, this is not a bug, but instead related to the way computers represent floating point numbers internally and handle floating point arithmetic.** It turns out that you and I don't think in floating point math, but computers do. And that "floating point" refers to a binary point, rather than a decimal one.

The numerical value that it's returning is in fact *extremely* close to 0 (which I think we can all agree is the "correct" decimal answer). What happened is that the sqrt function itself returned a number *extremely* close to 2, but this number couldn't be stored internally as *exactly* two because of the limitations of the floating point type. The *output* was the number "2" because Calculator just rounded it off for display purposes, knowing that "2" was the answer you expected. But then when you subtract 2 from that internally stored representation of `sqrt(4)`, you don't get exactly 0, because the number stored internally was not exactly 2.

Every programmer should really read ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which explains this behavior (particularly, the sections on "Precision" and "Binary to Decimal Conversion") and lots of other mind-boggling details about the way that computers represent numbers internally as floating point types.

Comment: You've explained why it happens, but from a users point of view it's still a bug.  Being able to explain why software behaves unexpectedly doesn't excuse the behaviour... at least according to the testers I work with.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a bug (computers work this way!). There are a lot of questions on this topic at SO. Search for "JavaScript math broken", for instance.

An experienced computer user should also recognize that -8.1648465955514287168521180122928e-39 is practically the same as zero.

If you want to avoid things like this, you can round every result when converting it to a string. -8.1648465955514287168521180122928e-39 would be rounded to 0. This, however, doesn't work if you are writing a very advanced calculator, able to work with for instance Planck's constant (if you did this, Planck's constant would be considered equal to zero, which is bad). A very good alternative is to work with symbolic math, but then it wouldn't take minutes to write a calculator, but months/years...

Comment: From a user experience point of view it's unexpected and gives an incorrect result.  This behaviour can fairly easily be encapsulated, so why isn't it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Its a common floating point problem. If you take for example `1/3` aqnd then multiply by `3` in floating point you wont get exactly `1` back, but `0.9999999999999999999999`, or `1.000000000000000000001`. Windows calculator used some algorithm to try and minimize cases like the i just explained, but it might be that they didn't handle all special cases....

Its not exactly a bug, more a usability problem, as they handle some of the cases but not all..

Comment: And not really a problem either, IMHO.

Comment: I'm afraid the example you give is not adequate for explaining the bug pointed out, as 4 and 2 (and even 3) can be precisely represented in IEEE FP format, while 1/3 cannot.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly more complicated than the normal floating point issues as Calc actually uses arbitrary precision mathematics. Crucially however it only seems to use infinite precision for basic operations, as stated by [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040525-00/?p=39193)

> Today, Calc's internal computations are done with infinite precision for basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) and 32 digits of precision for advanced operations (square root, transcendental operators).

So presumably the square root actually results in a value very close to, but not 2 but which is displayed as 2, after the precise subtraction you are left with a very close to 0 number which is not displayed as 0, is this a bug though? depends.

Answer (score 0):

With pure guessing, I would say it's because the calculator doesn't get exactly `2` as the result of the square root (depending on how it calculates the root). But when the result is away from zero, it simply rounds the display. But when the number is near zero, it shows the exact result.

For an own calculator, you probably won't get such results by simply not having such a high accuracy (which you usually don't have when using *normal* math features a programming language gives).